# What does the cat command in quotes in a string in perl do?

Tags: perl

```
#tf.pl
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use Util;
$file = shift;
$text = `cat $file`;
my @words = split_words ($text);
my @words = lc_words (@words);
my %count = count_hash(@words);
while (my ($w, $c) = each %count) {
    print "$w\t$c\n";
    $df{$w} = 1;
}
```

I came across that code on a website. On line 3 $file is given the name of the file that would have been supplied with the command line argument (correct me if I am wrong, I'm a Perl rookie)

On line 4 you see:

```
$text = `cat $file`;
```

I want to know what does this line do exactly? I know `cat filename` in shows you the content of the files in the terminal (again, correct me if wrong. Linux rookie too)

I asked this on IRC and someone said this was a bad way of doing something but I really want to know what this does more than knowing the better alternative of it

Comment: Note that the shebang line `#!/usr/local/bin/perl` does you no good unless it is the first line of the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *backticks* (so as to differentiate them from quotes `'` or `"`) run whatever they contain as an external application, then the assignment captures the output to the variable `$text`. The contents (inside the backticks) can be any runnable process:

```
$fileList = `ls`
$userList = `who`
```

and so on.

It's not usually a good idea since it ties the program to a specific operating system (those with a `cat` command in this case).

That *may* not be a problem but you should be aware that it reduces portability.

There are perfectly acceptable ways to already get the contents of a file into a variable in Perl, one that will work across all platforms (`open`, `while <BLAH>`, appending strings, and `close`), such as this sample program `xyzzy.pl` which reads itself in in two different ways (the first portable, the other not):

```
$sample1 = "";
open (INFILE, "xyzzy.pl") || die "Urk!";
while (<INFILE>) {
    $sample1 .= $_;
}
close (INFILE);

$sample2 = `cat xyzzy.pl`;

if ($sample1 ne $sample2) {
    print "Different\n";
    print "[$sample1]\n";
    print "[$sample2]\n";
} else {
    print "Same\n";
}
```

which outputs:

```
Same
```

Comment: So what's special here? the ` quotes, or the cat command being present inside a string?

Comment: @ProgrammingNoob, it's the quotes (I've updated the answer to be more explicit on that).

Comment: You should use the three-argument-version of `open` and lexical filehandles. And with the lower priority `or` you could even skip the braces. `open my $filehandle, '<' , "xyzzy.pl" or die "miserably";`

Comment: Yes, for a _more complicated_ program, you should. My intent however was not to provide a complex program, rather I just wanted to show that avoiding OS-specific staff was _possible._ Although there are certainly "better" ways to do it in Perl, the code as presented works fine, since it doesn't have to concern itself with scope or any of that other stuff big programs have to worry about.

Answer (score 7):

It runs the `cat` command on the named file (`$file` is expanded in the command line by Perl, not the shell) and captures the output in the string.  It's one way (not a particularly efficient way) of slurping the contents of the file into a variable in a single line of Perl code.

An alternative way to handle this is with the module [`File::Slurp`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3A%3ASlurp) or one of its relatives on CPAN, but it can also be done with somewhat more lines of code in a simple Perl function.  Ideally you write that function once and reuse it (someone already did that for you with File::Slurp).

This code works if the script file is called 'xx.pl' (or there is a file 'xx.pl' kicking around).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub slurp
{
    my($file) = @_;
    open my $handle, '<', $file or return undef;
    local $/ = undef;
    my $content = <$handle>;
    close $handle;
    return $content;
}

my $content = slurp("xx.pl");
print $content;
```

Comment: Yep, the same construct can be used in some shell languages.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to `qx` in [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html).  The backticks run the `cat` command and store the contents of the file into the `$text` scalar variable, newlines and all.